# OCI installed but not working

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I am using PHP with ORACLE; OCI is installed on the server and working fine when the script is run through command line from the same server. but when accessed from other computer through browser it does not work and gives below error message in the appache log:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Comment: echo a phpinfo() to check if oci is enabled

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the SELINUX value which was affecting this. The issue was related to LINUX other than Apache or PHP configuration.